# Binding between parent and child tables in WPF using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have two gridview control  like parent gridview like Order table   and child gridview Order_Detail Table . Both are binded to together . If one order is selected from Order table the corresponding order details are shown in the Order_Details table.The question is that I want to insert one record to Order_Details Table without losing the binding.But when i am trying to insert a record, it does not affecting.The datasource is not refreshing.. The code is given below.

How can i accomplish this? Plz help me...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    IBindingList l;       
    IBindingList p;     

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        l = dc.Orders.GetNewBindingList();           
        gridControl1.ItemsSource = l;           
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = gridControl2.ItemsSource;            
        System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Order_Detail> b = 
            (System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Order_Detail>)source;            

        b.Add(new Order_Detail { OrderID=1,ProductID=1});
        gridControl2.ItemsSource = b;
        gridControl2.RefreshData();//getting error

       // dc.SubmitChanges();      
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ranjith: At StackOverflow you better not just 'drop' a question and then leave to let is answer itself. Be there to respond to comments and answers, otherwise people will quickly lose interest.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, it is customary to declare properties that contain your data, in your case, your collections. You would then bind the `ItemsSource` property of a `ListView` to your property and declare your `GridView` inside the `ListView.View` property. Here is an example based on an example from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx).

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Details}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Using this setup, you can add new order objects to the Orders collection property and provided that you have used `ObservableCollection<T>` collections, the `GridView` will automatically update in the UI.